# Braintree Integration: Payment Method Token and Deletion

Tags: braintree

1. How to retrieve the saved (vaulted) payment methods for a Customer on the mobile app?
   Currently I am using `BTAPIClient::fetchPaymentMethodNonces()` method in the Braintree iOS API for this.
2. When a user selects a payment method to delete, the mobile app will send the selected 'payment method nonce' to the webserver to delete it.
   There is no API on the webserver to delete the payment method using the `nonce`. There is a Delete Payment Method API using `Token`, but I am wondering how will the webserver identify which `Token` to use, as the mobile app only sends the `nonce`.
3. Finally, why do we need to save the `Payment Method Token` on the webserver?
   If the mobile app uses only the `nonce` for communication with the webserver, why do we even need a `Token`?

Comment: Full Disclosure: I work at Braintree. This question covers a broad range of topics from preferred methods / best practices to the motivations behind product design decisions. Questions like these are more appropriate for the [Braintree Support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) team. Please reach out there to get more help.

Comment: @jake I did reach out to Braintree support team, but didn't get concrete answers to my questions. My question is not broad I feel. I just want to know what's the use of Token and how to delete a payment method.